# Where I Can get my karbonn a9's Driver for PC [Tianyu HSUSB Driver]?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb-drivers, karbonn-a9

I am having karbonn a9 and I am not able to install Tianyu HSUSB driver for my laptop.

I have visited 100s of site but not got a single Driver which is proper.

Please help me I am getting error like following image when I connect my device to computer.[image]

Comment: Have you tried Kosh's [Universal USB driver](http://adbdriver.com/)? Should work for many devices (not sure about yours, but certainly worth a try).